# Eval user code without global scope or track workers memory consumption

Tags: javascript, eval, worker, deno

Any way to restrict global scope access for some `eval`ed code? By global i mean everything including native constructors (`Number`, `Crypto`, `Worker`, etc) and native variables (`atob`, `console`, `window`, etc).

The goal of this: repeatedly eval user code on server side (inside worker) and do not run out of memory cos of global scope abusing.

If there some solution with tracking workers memory consumption in `Deno` environtment then id be glad to see it too.

Comment: What do you mean by "*do not run out of memory cos of global scope abusing*"? If care about memory consumption, a simple `var i=0, arr=[]; while(true) arr.push(i);` will cause the same problems without using any globals.

Comment: @Bergi well if millions of users will repeatedly push millons of huge chunks of data inside global variables (so i cant just clear it after every `eval`) my servers memory will collapse.

Comment: @Bergi i can terminate worker by timeout but i cant restore his global scope to default after every `eval`.

Comment: Wait, you want to `eval` multiple times inside the *same* worker, and even have the worker shared by different users? That's highly insecure, don't do that.

Comment: @Bergi one worker for one user's function that can be `eval`ed millions of times with different arguments inside this one worker. There can be also millions of that users and their functions but they all share one server and one memory.

Comment: I don't think you would care about restoring global state or limiting access to globals inside the worker, it's just the responsibility of the user that his function doesn't leak memory across many runs - you would just kill his worker when it needs too much memory. Sadly [this doesn't seems possible](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/1639#issuecomment-590531922) yet.

Comment: @Bergi i think you still dont get what i need. Its worker that ran on server side with `Deno` which transpile `JS` code to `V8` and `Rust` what make possible to use `JS` as server language.

Comment: I will overlook the "*Deno which transpile JS code to V8 and Rust*" misunderstanding, but yes I understood that you are executing js on the server using deno.